# Freezing boiled octopus

Tags: frozen, safety, grill, octopus

I've bought a frozen fresh octopus. As most recipes suggest I'm planning to boil it, and then char it on the grill.

The problem is that it's pretty huge and we are only 2 people.
Would it be ok if I was to freeze part of the boiled octopus to grill at a later time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can most certainly freeze some of it for cooking later. I have heard that this actually improves texture by tenderizing it. I'd suggest doing so in a freezer-safe bag with as much air removed as possible. Depending on portion size, lay it flat or in pieces that will be easy for you to portion later if you won't eat the rest at once. That will make it easier to use without having to partially re-thaw.

Comment: @moscafj -- curious why you removed the name. Is it standard protocol in this forum to not address people directly?

Comment: @myklblkl  seems like general practice in answers.  More common that people are addressed specifically in comments.